# Unable to insert data into sql server using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my code for inserting data into my SQL Server database. I have established the connection to my SQL Server. But when I debug my code, the textboxes appear as they should, but when I type data into it, and click submit, it does not show up in the database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection strcon;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        string sqlstr;
        string constr = @"Data Source=HAVINES\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserLoginDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

        strcon = new SqlConnection(constr);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        strcon.Open();

        if (ds.Tables != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                sqlstr = "insert into RegisterTable values(";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7] + "',";
                sqlstr = sqlstr + "'" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][8] + "')";

                cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, strcon);

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // do something when ds.Tables is null or ds.Tables doesn't have any elements
        }

        strcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: First, read about SQL Injection and parameterized queries. Second, you are not filling `ds` in this code, so `ds.Tables.Count` is 0.

Comment: Try to debug and check. because i don't think your if block is getting executed. and while inserting data why do you need to use datasets.. you can get values directly from your textbox.

Comment: Two more things - You should always specifiy the list of columns in an insert into statement, and you should read about `IDisposable` and the `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Some Comment That I Think It Can Make Your Code Better  :

- If It's Only One Table then Why DataSet ?! Use DataTable
- The += on the sqlstr
- Adding `Using` To The SQLConnection Will Elimnate The Need To Calling `Con.Close()`
- `i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1` ... is't this    the same as `i <
  ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`
- Consider Using CmdParameters .

Coming To The Main Problem ... You Are Creating A New Empty Instance Of The DataSet Class and Checking If it's Empty Or Not With Out Trying To Fill It With Any Thing

Comment: Actually, that's not the main problem. The main problem is not using parameters. that's just what's causing the insert to fail.

Comment: even If There Was Parameters ...What Data Will Be Inserted ?..The Condition Will Always be False So it Doesn't Matter How Is He Going To Insert ..The Compiler Won't Reach This Code Any Way

Comment: The compiler will reach the code, but it will never run. And while you are correct when you say the data will not be inserted even with parameters, you are missing the big picture here - and that's teaching whoever reads this question and doesn't know about parameterized queries the correct way of working with sql. This is why I think it's the main issue for the OP, bigger then getting this insert to work.

Comment: Zohar, the dataset is created two lines before, with no efforts to fill it. Tables will definitely be an empty collection of 0 items, so mostafa is correct in his assertion of false, not because of the null check, but because of Count>0 check. I wholly agree though with your assertion that Havines needs much more tuition about proper ways to do data access.. It goes beyond parameters though; nearly everything about the posted code sample needs improvement

Comment: @CaiusJard hence my comments to the question: 1. Sql injection and parameterized queries, 2. empty ds, 3 columns list in insert commads, 4 IDisposable and using.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your post is a particularly horrendous way to write database insert code, for a multitude of reasons, some already covered in comment on your main post.

Please see this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6.aspx

It's a set of tutorials by Microsoft on how to correctly do data access using datasets. While it is aimed at windows forms users more than asp, the principles are identical and you'll set yourself up for life if you follow them. Start with Creating a Simple Data Application, follow it (do it as a windows forms project first, so you're not trying to wrangle learning a new data access strategy together with adapting a tutorial from winforms to webforms) and in 15 minutes you'll know how to properly do your data access. I promise you this will save you hours of frustration today alone, never mind the rest of your life

I accept that this isn't a "here's how to fix your broken solution" answer, it's a "here's how you really should be doing it, please throw away what you've done and approach it like this" which may be anathema to you right now, but in a year's time you will hopefully look at the code you wrote in your original post with shocked horror.

We've all done it, but you really need to get on the right road now before it becomes ingrained and you're unwilling to change. Do things the way MS teach and your code will be 3 lines long, readable, secure, maintainable and it'll work. Do your database access like you're currently doing, and one day you'll be at the centre of one of those "I changed an ID number in the URL and saw someone else's credit card details" scandals, or worse..

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing new Dataset

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Which mean there is no table in this dataset

```
ds.Tables != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0
```

This condition will always return false and your query will not be executed

1) Always use parameterized Query because this query that you are using is not secure and if there is single quotation mark (') in you text that you are inserting or updating will break the execution.

2) you can also use bulk update for this [click here for bulk update table](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy--Bulk-Insert-records-and-Update-existing-rows-if-record-exists-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)